# Is there a way to loop through directories in one r-script file

Tags: r, loops, directory

I have a couple hundred folders (observations), each with a few text files (each one is a trial). I was able to figure out, with some help, how to loop through the text files and create one image of the graph so it is saved in the folder/directory...

```
setwd("~/data/observation1")

library(ggplot2)

files <- list.files(pattern=".txt")
for (i in files){
  mylist <- lapply(setNames(files, files), read.table, header = T)
  mylist <- lapply(names(mylist), function(i) {cbind(mylist[[i]], ID = i)})
  mydata <- do.call(rbind, mylist)
}

ggplot(mydata, aes(x = place, y = firing_rate, colour = ID)) + geom_point() + geom_path()
dev.print(pdf, 'observation1.pdf')
```

It works perfectly, but now I am trying to zoom out, so to say, so I can apply the aforementioned code to all the other folders/directories (observation2, observation3, etc.) without having to go through and change the setwd() one by one.

Additionally, it would also be great if I could somehow just save all the plots (one for each folder) as one big pdf with a few hundred pages.

Any advice for how to do these two things or even start them is greatly appreciated and I will gladly answer any questions.

Comment: Why don't you want to use setwd() to change folders? You could do it in one big for.

Comment: You might consider the `purrr` package to simplify this. https://serialmentor.com/blog/2016/6/13/reading-and-combining-many-tidy-data-files-in-R

Comment: You can get the full path of the file using the argument `full.names = TRUE`  in `list.files`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach, you can modify to suit your needs:

```
setwd("~/data")

my_folders <- c("observation1", "observation2", "observation3") # etc.

for(j in my_folders) {
  files <- list.files(path = j, pattern=".txt", full.names=T)
  # ... etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a vector of your observations with

```
vector <- dir(path="~/data/")  # this will list all your observations
mylist<- list()
for ( i in 1:length(vector){
setwd(paste0("~/data/",vector[i]))

files[[i]] <- list.files(pattern=".txt")
for (j in files[[i]]){
  mylist[[i]] <- lapply(setNames(files[[i]], files[[i]]), read.table, header = T)
  mylist[[i]] <- lapply(names(mylist[[i]]), function(j) {cbind(mylist[[i]], ID = j)})
  mydata[[i]] <- do.call(rbind, mylist[[i]])
  }
  }
```

then you can plot each file in mylist

Comment: It gives me a "Error in files[[i]] <- list.files(pattern = ".txt") : more elements supplied than there are to replace" message. I'm thinking the issue is some kink in the double nested for loop but I cannot make out exactly where.